# Should the slack api x-oauth-scopes response header match what my app manifest shows?

Tags: slack-api

I recently reduced the scopes my app requests. My app manifest looks like:

```yaml
oauth_config:
  scopes:
    bot:
      - app_mentions:read
      - chat:write
      - commands
      - users:read
      - users:read.email
```

But when I use the following [request with a bot token as described by the API docs](https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth-scopes#working-with-scopes):

```
curl \
  -I \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxb-0123456789-0123456789012-0123456789abcdefghijklmn" \
  https://slack.com/api/files.list \
  | fgrep scope
```

I get the following:

```
x-accepted-oauth-scopes: files:read
x-oauth-scopes: incoming-webhook,usergroups:write,usergroups:read,chat:write,commands,channels:history,groups:history,im:history,mpim:history,users:read,users:read.email,app_mentions:read
```

The scopes listed in `x-oauth-scopes` look to be the scopes my app had requested prior to me trying to reduce the set to only what I actually need. I've already tried reinstalling my app into my workspace.